# Round edges of a custom view not working as expected when using path

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, bezier

I want to draw a custom view , [image: kind of expected result]

in this image I need to draw rounded corners of the rectangle

I wrote this code

```
class RoundedRectUsingPath @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

  private val roundCorner = 10f

  private val paint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.RED
    isAntiAlias = true
    pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(roundCorner)
    setShadowLayer(10f, -2f, 2f, android.graphics.Color.BLACK)

  }

  private var path = Path()

  override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    val left = 10f
    val top = 0f
    val avatarRadius = 30f
    val shapeBounds = RectF(left, top+20, left + width - 40, top + height -20)

    val leftCutoutPoint = PointF(left, shapeBounds.bottom/2)
    val rightCutOutBounds = PointF(shapeBounds.right, shapeBounds.bottom/2)
    val leftAvatarBounds = fromCircle(center = leftCutoutPoint, radius = avatarRadius)
    val rightAvatarBounds = fromCircle(center = rightCutOutBounds, radius = avatarRadius)

    path = Path().apply {
      moveTo(shapeBounds.left, shapeBounds.top)
      arcTo(leftAvatarBounds, -90f, 180f, false)
      lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomLeft.x, shapeBounds.bottomLeft.y)
      lineTo(shapeBounds.bottomRight.x, shapeBounds.bottomRight.y)
      arcTo(rightAvatarBounds, 90f, 180f, false)
      lineTo(shapeBounds.topRight.x, shapeBounds.topRight.y)
      close()
    }
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
  }


  fun fromLTRB(left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) =
    RectF(left, top, right, bottom)

  fun fromLTWH(left: Float, top: Float, width: Float, height: Float) =
    fromLTRB(left, top, left + width, top + height)

  fun fromCircle(center: PointF, radius: Float) =
    fromCenter(
      center = center,
      width = radius,
      height = radius
    )

  fun fromCenter(center: PointF, width: Float, height: Float) =
    fromLTRB(
      center.x - width,
      center.y - height,
      center.x + width,
      center.y + height
    )

  fun RectF.inflate(delta: Float): RectF {
    return fromLTRB(
      left - delta,
      top - delta,
      right + delta,
      bottom + delta
    )
  }
}
```

but when I am using    `pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(roundCorner).` where round corner is 10fthe image is changing to this  [image: rounded corner image]

1. Here you can see the cutout shape changes, which is not expected.
2. And the topleft corner is not perfectly round but a straight line
   between 2 points.

The expected is rounded corners with perfect cutouts, I tried many different ways to acheive this but none of them are working for me.

Comment: What does this have to do with Bezier curves?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two issues:

1. The top left corner is not really rounded but looks to be just a line;
2. The cutouts look to be less rounded when using *CornerPathEffect*.

This looking buggy to me. Maybe someone will have a more direct fix, but I recommend that you take a look at [MaterialShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to draw your shape.

[Here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/android-tips-advanced-shapes-for-your-drawables-5a7186e68fd) is some more information on *MaterialShapeDrawable*. It looks like the "ticket" shape is what you are looking for.

***From your update to the questions:***

1. Here you can see the cutout shape changes, which is not expected.

This still looks like a bug to me. However, if you add one to `leftAvatarBounds.top += 1`, the left cutoff will be correct. Why? I don't know. Adding `rightAvatarBounds.bottom += 1` to the right cutoff works for that side.

2. And the topleft corner is not perfectly round but a straight line between 2 points.

Do not start the path in a corner but within one side.

You can get your code working by changing the path calculation to the following:

```
path = Path().apply {
    moveTo(shapeBounds.right / 2, shapeBounds.top)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.left, shapeBounds.top)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.left, leftAvatarBounds.top)
    leftAvatarBounds.top += 1
    arcTo(leftAvatarBounds, -90f, 180f, false)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.left, shapeBounds.bottom)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.right, shapeBounds.bottom)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.right, rightAvatarBounds.bottom)
    rightAvatarBounds.bottom += 1
    arcTo(rightAvatarBounds, 90f, 180f, false)
    lineTo(shapeBounds.right, shapeBounds.top)
    close()
}
```

This is what is displayed with the above changes:

[image]

Although this works, you may not feel comfortable, as I would not, relying upon the magical addition of one to the avatar bounds.

I went ahead and coded up a *MaterialShapeDrawable* which I mentioned would be an alternate solution:

```
class TicketView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val ticketShapePathModel = ShapeAppearanceModel
        .Builder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 10f)
        .setLeftEdge(TicketEdgeTreatment(30f))
        .setRightEdge(TicketEdgeTreatment(30f))
        .build()

    private var ticket: MaterialShapeDrawable

    init {
        ticket = MaterialShapeDrawable(ticketShapePathModel).apply {
            fillColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
            shadowRadius = 10
            shadowCompatibilityMode = MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_ALWAYS
            setShadowColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        ticket.bounds = Rect(0, 0, w, h)
        ticket.bounds.inset(10, 10)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        ticket.draw(canvas)
    }
}

private class TicketEdgeTreatment(
    private val size: Float
) : EdgeTreatment() {
    override fun getEdgePath(
        length: Float,
        center: Float,
        interpolation: Float,
        shapePath: ShapePath
    ) {
        val circleRadius = size * interpolation
        shapePath.lineTo(center - circleRadius, 0f)
        shapePath.addArc(
            center - circleRadius, -circleRadius,
            center + circleRadius, circleRadius,
            180f,
            -180f
        )
        shapePath.lineTo(length, 0f)
    }
}
```

This displays as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but I am aware of the issues you mentioned above, I forgot to mention the 1st one though. I'll edit my question, but is there any solution to fix above issues, as I have gone through the docs and came up with above code.

Comment: I do think that _MaterialShapeDrawable_ is your best bet. But, if you want to continue along the current path (no pun intended), I can get the top left corner rounded. As for the cutouts, it looks like they should be half circles. Is that correct? @Luther

Comment: yes, if I remove pathEffect = CornerPathEffect(roundCorner) , the cutouts are working as expected. The first image that I have shared does not have CornerPathEffect(roundCorner). Adding CornerPathEffect is causing the issue. @cheticamp